# How do you run tests in anaconda mode?

Tags: python, testing

Elpy has support for running test using your test runner.

Looking at anaconda it does not seem to do the same functionality is there a package that can detect all your tests and let you run them individually using anaconda mode ?

I am looking for a way I can also customise this on a per project bases using dir-locals as the tests will actually need to run inside a container.

Comment: can you not run anaconda mode and  elpy in the same buffer?

Comment: Possibly but they both do very similar things so seems a shame to pull them both in feels like there should be some other method